# jQuery conflict between two libraries

Tags: javascript, jquery

I faced confuing problem on my website.

I am using two jquery libraries one 1.5.1 and other 3.2.1. For latest version of  jQuery I am using noConflict mode

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
      var inst = jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
```

Everything is Ok, but when the customer is choosing shiping method on my website it shows an error and other my scripts doesnt work.

[image]

But jQuery library 3.2.1 should be in noConflict mode. And there is no conflicts and errors on the other pages of website.

I dont know how can i fix this issue.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure but you may have to pass `true` to `noConflict`. See the notes in the doc https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/ about using multiple versions (they don't recommend it) and potential need to relinquish the jQuery name under such circumstances.

Comment: I dont know why, but when I use true it doesnt work at all.

Answer (score 1):

**jQuery .live() has been removed in version 1.9 onwards.**

So you must change:

```
.live(events, function)
```

should map to:

```
.on(eventType, selector, function)
```

**Below are reference links:**

http://api.jquery.com/on/

http://api.jquery.com/off/

The page for `live()` shows how to convert to `on()`:

http://api.jquery.com/live/

**Updated:**

You can free up jQuery with `noConflict(true)`. Though, if you take this route, you'll definitely want an alias as neither `$` nor `jQuery`:

```
var jq = jQuery.noConflict(true);
```

Or may be you can do like this:

```
var jq = $.noConflict();
```

then you can call jquery function with `jq`.

```
jq('#selector');
```

Comment: He's using 1.5.1 **and** 3.2.1, thus he's expecting `live` to be available. Getting the page to work using both versions seems to be the point of the question (and not how to upgrade). Per their docs he probably just has to pass true to noConflict. Though they do not recommend using multiple versions, it appears to be possible.

Comment: Ok. You are right. So you can either pass `true` or there is an alternative that I have suggested in my updated answer.

Comment: I know that live() have been removed, therefore I am using two jQuery libraries and one of them is 1.5.1. 

I dont know why the second jQuery library is throwing error, it should be in noConflict mode. And this mode works perfect on other pages of my website except of one page.

Comment: Did you tried what I have mentioned under `Updated:`

Comment: When I use: var jq = jQuery.noConflict(true); it shows an error that jq is not a function 

But when I use: var jq = $.noConflict(); it works except one page...

Therefore I dont understand why it shows that jQuery 3.2.1 .live() is not a function if that script use normal $ 

and other scripts with "jq" works fine

And when I delete link to jQuery 3.2.1 it also works fine